# Outputting anchor class in PHP While() loop seems inconsistent

Tags: php

I have two fields in a SQL table, `done` and `current`. Both have data that is either 1 (yes) or 0 (false).

Within my `while()` PHP loop that creates my elements, I have the following code:

```
$current=mysql_result($result,$i,"current");
$done=mysql_result($result,$i,"done");

if ($done == 1){
$doneorcurrent = "done";
} 

if($current == "1"){
$doneorcurrent = "current";
}else {$doneorcurrent = "";}
```

Then I call `$doneorcurrent` using the following:

`<a class="article <? echo $doneorcurrent ?>"</a>`

The problem is that even though one of my `done` fields has a 1, it never shows up. I've dinked around with the code for a while now, and once I made it so it was the reverse - only `done` showed up, and not `current`.

Is there a better way I should be doing this? See http://www.bavarianblue.com/to-do-list/ for an example. The titles of each task are wrapped in a class that should contain `current` or `done`. As you can see, the rest of the data outputs correctly in the `While()` loop, so it doesn't seem like that is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `if` statement will always set `$doneorcurrent` to either `"current"` or `""` (empty). You can fix this by using an `ifelse` statement like this:

```
if ($done == 1){
  $doneorcurrent = "done";
}elseif($current == "1"){
  $doneorcurrent = "current";
}else {
  $doneorcurrent = "";
}
```

As a side note, I don't really understand your database design. why are "done" and "current" stored in different tables? Couldn't it just be a flag in a single column in a single table?

Comment: yeah actually it could... `current` was an afterthought from `done`, but you are absolutely right!

Comment: And thanks for the quick answer - I wasn't realizing I was cancelling myself out.